# How to display image in angular?

Tags: angularjs

How to display image in angular?

````
<div><img  class="images" ng-src="{{./resources/img/new.png}}"/></div>

<div><img  class="images" src="./resources/img/new.png"/></div>```
````

Comment: Tried with above things but it didn't work

Comment: Try: `src="https://anyimage.com/sample.jpg"` if that worked then there is a problem in the path of an image

Comment: Image paths do not usually have a ./ in the front, try resources/img/new.png

Comment: @LilasaikumarreddyReddy keep your resources in assets folder in angular project then set `<img  class="images" src="assets/resources/img/new.png"/>`

Comment: also if you need to set the image url dynamically from any variable the use keep your resources in assets folder in angular project then set `<img  class="images" [src]="imageUrl"/>`

Comment: check your console log and post it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Learn angular template binding (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).
If you have image in local like (./resources/img/new.png) you can use normal html source tag

```
<img  class="images" src="./resources/img/new.png"/>
```

Or your image comes from server or dynamically  that time you have to bind that like

```
img = this.imageSource
<img  class="images" src={{img}}/> or
<img class="images" [src]="img"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

**How the Angular CLI Deals with Images**

Remember when we used the `npm run build` or `ng build --prod` command? Angular CLI moved all of our assets into the `dist` folder. It will do the same when it sees that there are images inside the assets folder.

All we have to do is reference these images in our templates with a path that starts inside the src folder.

For instance, if we have an image at `src/assets/img/logo.png,` we would add this to our template:

template:
 
  `<img src="assets/img/logo.png">`

Adding An Image to the Assets Folder
The assets folder that the Angular CLI generated for us is the perfect place to use for storing images.

Let's go grab the Angular logo from angular.io.

```
https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/logo-nav@2x.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Simple and Easy solutions for your problem.

The more complex code will confuse further.

**Angular js file:**

```
$scope.imageAddress='resources/img/new.png';

// The Path has to be exact.
// Check your project folder hierarchy for that.
```

**HTML file:**

```
<body ng-app = "myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <img alt="" ng-src="{{ imageAddress }}" />
    </div>
</body>
```

And Your path will be according to the HTML file in which you had written your Image source code.

eg:- If your ng-src is in Index.html path: **resources/index.html**

and your new.png is in path: **resources/views/images/new.png**

then **$scope.imageAddress='views/images/new.png';**

**One more thing:**
**Prefer ng-src over src.**

Answer (score 0):

Install *serve-static* :

```
npm install --save @nestjs/serve-static
```

Then, in *app.module.ts*  (Nestjs) :

```
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import {  resolve } from 'path';  
.... 
@Module({
  imports: [....,
        ServeStaticModule.forRoot(
      (() => {
        const publicDir = resolve('uploads');
        return {
          rootPath: publicDir,
          serveRoot: '/public',
          exclude: ['/api*'],
        };
      })()
    ),]
```

Use *resolve('mydir')* to url where storage files and view ex. http://localhost:3000/public/image.png